# PHP-FFMPEG Waveform is not clean, is it a bug?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, waveform

I made a waveform through sample code :

```
$waveform = $audio->waveform(2000, 500, array('#FFA500'));
$waveform->save('waveform.png');
```

But result has some noise in top & bottom of edges.
How can make it better?

PHP-FFMpeg : 23 | FFMpeg : 2023-02-27-git-891ed24f77 (Win X64) | PHP : 8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can do some core modification in line 140 of:

```
src\FFMpeg\Media\Waveform.php
```

```
//'showwavespic=colors='.$this->compileColors().':s='.$this->width.'x'.$this->height,
'showwavespic=draw=full:colors='.$this->compileColors().':s='.$this->width.'x'.$this->height,
```

It should make better result.

Comment: Yep! it's working but I think it should be updated in PHP-FFMPEG library in Github.